# Undefined function when assigning to onclick()

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble figuring out why I am getting an error in the console log telling me that the function weather() is undefined. I researched the issue and the only thing I could find was information about lexical scopes but that didn't seem to fix the error I was getting. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

This was a test application I am working on for learning purposes so I can fix some issues on an application at work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="main.css">
<script type="text/javascript" scr="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<h1>The content of the document......</h1>

<input type="button" name="City: " value="London" onclick="weather()">


<script type="text/javascript">
var api_path = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="
var city = "London"
var api_key = "&appid=988bd58ad518778f5761aad912ed1ce8";

function weather (){
    $.getJSON(api_path + city + api_key, function(data) {
    var items = [];
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + value + "</li>" );
  });
 .appendTo( "body" );
}); 
};
weather();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have an error in your code. `.appendTo("body")` is after a `;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove ; before .appendTo( "body" )